Is the depressurization performance of fairing during ascent ever tested on the ground before flight?
Fairing is the upper part of the launch vehicle that covers payload. This payload is very sensitive because of the high speed of vehicle produces a lot of heat. Fairing bears all of it. The pressure in the surrounding decreases so the inner pressure of the fairing stays constant, for example. See for example answers to my previous question what kind of valves are used in payload fairing for venting?
If it were to stay constant, then a fairing would likely "pop" open a pressure-relieving hole during ascent, ending the mission. Therefore 100 kPa is not acceptable and this is decreased through vents.

I would like to know; is a fairing venting system ever tested on ground for its depressurization behavior?
What are acceptance and qualification tests?


If you got a very big vacuum test chamber, the depressurization of a fairing may be tested on the ground. For a vacuum test of the payload a large chamber is needed anyway.

As far as I am aware, fairings are not generally airtight.

what are the standards?

different questions, but related and potentially helpful: related: Pressure inside a launch fairing - falcon 9 and what kind of valves are used in payload fairing for venting? and Why not use alternative/low-pressure atmospheres in fairings during launch? and Could a fairing vacuum protect the payload from acoustic loads?

I certainly know that there is no vacuum inside the fairing. Fairings are designed to sustain just the pressure difference. Because initially, on ground, the pressure (inside and outside) are the same. The pressure in the atmosphere , then , decreases like a reversed S shape curve. So the fairing pressure should be eliminated. Otherwise the final pressure inside the fairing would be 100kPa which is not bearable. This decrease in pressure is fullfilled by vents. Now, how can a fairing may be tested on ground that it would release the pressure by the same rate as its supposed to be.

I've adjusted the title to better reflect your question, which is quite interesting and answerable, and added some emphasis to your explanations. Certainly venting systems are not just big holes or pipes directly connecting the outdoors to the payload area; there'd be insects, birds, dust, humidity, alligators (humor)... Obviously I'm thinking specifically of Florida or French Guiana. They require one-way valves of some kind, letting pressure OUT to the atmosphere, but not back IN (there'd be a separate source of clean dry air) & these would very likely need some kind of overpressure testing.

It is done, but it seems to be ancillary to fairing separation tests. Perhaps the separation tests are so high-stakes that the venting prior to it is not really talked about.  For example

The jettison test was a simulation
of the event described
above, wherein the two halves of the
payload fairing separate after the launch vehicle clears the Earth's atmosphere.
The test program
consisted
of performing
two separate payload fairing jettison events at a simulated
altitude of
85,000 feet (chamber pressure = 17 torr). After the inner metal door and the outer concrete
chamber doors were closed, an approximately
five hour pumpdown
was performed,
and after a
short countdown
a switch was flipped, immediately
supplying power to the explosive
bolts,
initiating the jettison event.

So for this test, the fairing was placed in a large vacuum chamber at ambient pressure, the doors to the chamber were closed, and the vacuum chamber pumped down. During this pumpdown, the interior of the fairing would have been venting down as the vacuum chamber pressure decreased.
It took five hours rather than five minutes as it would in a real launch. Perhaps it's impractical to do a "realtime" test of large fairings depressurizing because the large facilities can't pump down that fast.
Nonetheless, this does describe a ground test of fairing depressurization.
Source: Ground test program for new Atlas payload fairings
There are a number of videos on youtube showing fairing separation tests in vacuum chambers (many in Plum Brook, unsurprising because of its size). Here are a couple of examples from different eras.






Any test like this would involve a similar pumpdown and fairing depressurization.

I'm sure the valves can and will be tested on the ground by putting increased pressure on the "inside" side of the valve and confirming that it opens as expected, but yeah, it's not really feasible to recreate the exact conditions of a launch outside of an actual launch.
